# How to get my smartThings python3 script working on apache webserver as a cgi file

Tags: python-3.x, apache, python-asyncio, aiohttp, centos8

My father and I are making a webserver so Grafana will be able to access a few python scripts; Grafana only allows you to add *links* to buttons. Earlier today we created the webserver. Then I started work on two python files, "smartThingy.py" and "printLight.cgi". After those were created I put them on the network hard drive and my dad moved them onto the centos 8 machine that was running apache. It worked after getting the files to not be in DOS format. Currently, we are getting a small error https://pastebin.com/TXhXFPwm . Can someone please help debug the code so we can turn on and off a light by going to *http://PrivateIpOfTheServer/cgi-bin/printLight.cgi*

Here is my code. Its only missing the bits that allows it to output text onto the page.

https://pastebin.com/qn2EMYhZ  - smartThingy.py (a module so it will be easier to create more cgi files)

https://pastebin.com/9J8HMYS7  - printLight.cgi (controls light above 3d printers)

Edit: I am using https://pypi.org/project/pysmartthings/ for smartThings

Answer (score 0):

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6 from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 443.

*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (47.5 confidence) suggests   ******************

If you want to allow httpd to can network connect
Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'httpd_can_network_connect' boolean.

Do
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

SELinux was just being mean to us.